# Changing boolean from true to false and use it in if() afterward using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, boolean, var

I have tried several ways to implement the output from a boolean to an if-statement. Somehow I do it wrong. I'm able to change the value of the boolean and console.log it, so that should be right. I then try to use it in an if-statement, but somehow it is ignored and doesn't give the expected outcome. 
This is my code:

```
    var heroVelX = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;
    var heroVelY = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().y;
    var speed = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(heroVelX, 2) + Math.pow(heroVelY, 2));
    var moveOn = "";

    function delay(){   
        moveOn = Boolean(speed<1.5);
        console.log("Speed = " + speed + "  " + moveOn);    
    };  

    setTimeout(delay, 3500);

    // These are the conditions I have tried using. I can see in console.log that the value is changed. But somehow it is ignored? All the other conditions are accepted in the if-statement.       
    // moveOn ===!false
    // moveOn == true

    if(!game.currentHero.IsAwake() || moveOn === !false || heroX<0 || heroX >game.currentLevel.foregroundImage.width ){
            // then delete the old hero
            box2d.world.DestroyBody(game.currentHero);
            game.currentHero = undefined;
            // and load next hero
            game.mode = "load-next-hero";
        }
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `setTimeout(delay, 3500);` this line will run, then *continue* to the next (your condition) where `moveOn` is still `""` as `delay()` has not yet executed.

Comment: How can I then stop the program until moveOn has changed? Or is there another solution?

Comment: The `setTimeout` schedules the call to `delay()` so if you want stuff to run *after* delay, put it inside `delay()`

Comment: Can't I set `moveOn = false;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong...

First of all, it's horrible to define a var as a String, and after that change it to boolean.

Secondly, put your boolean into a different log, and use dir instead.

The if statement its too confusing.

And there is no need to cast to Boolean.

Take a look at this:

```
var heroVelX = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;
var heroVelY = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().y;
var speed = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(heroVelX, 2) + Math.pow(heroVelY, 2));
var moveOn = false;

function delay(){   
    moveOn = (speed<1.5) ? true : false;
    console.log("Speed = " + speed);
    console.dir(moveOn);


};  

setTimeout(delay, 3500);

if(!game.currentHero.IsAwake() || moveOn || heroX<0 || heroX >game.currentLevel.foregroundImage.width ){
        // then delete the old hero
        box2d.world.DestroyBody(game.currentHero);
        game.currentHero = undefined;
        // and load next hero
        game.mode = "load-next-hero";
    }
```

Comment: I see the point of declaring a string and then change it to a boolean. .dir is new to me and doesn't give me any feedback? How can I improve the if-statement? I tried to use your suggestion, but it doesn't solve my problem?

Comment: The idea of use .dir instead of .log, is because .log will cast the value to string, and the cast to string of a boolean is an empty string that you won't see. .dir will show you the real value of the var. Also see my code. I removed all the operators of the moveOn on the if statement. A boolean it self its enough to be true/false in an if-statment. What behavior are you having now?

Comment: I've removed the delay() function, since it interrupts the Boolean. It wont pass it on. It's not optimal, but it's okay.